# Фоновый сервис ПУШ реализация сегодня!

Tags: android, kotlin

В данный момент сообщения доставляю через FCM и создаю onMessageReceived конструктором сам ПУШ вот обычный код

```
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "chat")
//.setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ic_push_ico), 128, 128, false))
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_chat_24            )
    .setLargeIcon(getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(applicationContext,R.drawable.ic_logo128))
    .setColor(color)
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_push_chat_24, "Прочитать", pendingIntent)
    .setContentTitle(bodydatajson.getString("pushtitle"))
    .setContentText(bodydatajson.getString("msgmanager"))
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setOngoing(false)
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
    val notificationId = (1000000000..1999999999).random()
    notify(notificationId, builder.build()) // посылаем уведомление
}
```

Если телефон спит сообщения не приходят, только после пробуждения.

1. Подскажите пожалуйста на сегодняшний день если мое приложение от sdk 28 и выше
   Как лучше организовать доставку и оповещения PUSH в фоне?
2. Как сделать так чтобы не показывать всплывающее сообщение в определенном активити, когда приложение открыто?

Comment: Ваш код - это не создание пуша через конструктор. Это создание уведомления через билдер. Сообщения могут не приходить в фоне из-за Doze Mode. В теории обойти Doze Mode можно через выставление приоритета отправки пушей, но тут может потребоваться личное разрешение гугла на такое, т.к. это может заметно сказаться на времени жизни девайса (будет сажать батарею). Чтобы не показывать в определённой активити - можно в этой активити какую-то глобальную переменную менять с false на true и в зависимости от неё не показывать или нет уведомление

Comment: Не совсем понятно в какой момент менять на true и как отловить само события PUSH.

Открыто активити чата и в нем не нужен всплывающий ПУШ.

Comment: Менять true на false можно в onStop/onStart, например (или даже в onPause/onResume). Вы уже отлавливаете событие - в onMessageReceived. В нём как раз можете и проверять значение переменной, которое зависит от жизненного цикла вашей актвиити.